# stop a function when I access another state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers. a page called page1 and another called page2. on page1 I have a code that runs an animation.I have a function that calls itself infinitely. in this line.

**.each('end', tick)** when the animation ends, it start tick() again.

```
function tick(){
 console.log("hello");
 .
 .
 .
//line 190
 paths.attr('transform', null)
 .transition()
 .duration(duration)
 .ease('linear')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(now - (limit - 1) * duration) + ')')
 .each('end', tick) //when the transition ends, it start tick() again
}
```

This is fine, because it is an infinite animation. I put console.log("hello") in the **tick** function, then every time this function is executed, the word "hello" is written to the console. so far so good !. when I change the controller, ie when I click to go to page2, my previous animation is still running, and I can still see the console.log("hello") of the function that is in my first controller.

How can I stop this function when I change controller?

this is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/66cK7gWTNQNh4vmC2lmp?p=preview

Comment: is there some condition you can check prior to calling `tick()`?  For example, `.each('end', function() { if(condition) { tick(); } })`

Comment: @snapjs any condition would be alright

Comment: @aaron yes, but it not works for me. I have an error with that..

Comment: See **ug_**'s updated answer.

Comment: I am trying this but it not works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the scope being destroyed and stop your animation loop:

```
function MyController($scope) {
  var animating = true;
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    animating = false;
  });

  function tick() {
    if (!animating) return;
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

Read about Angular's scope `$destroy` event here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy

Comment: friend I tried this, but it does not work for me. in fact it causes me an error. $scope.on is not a function. And is destroy. thanks!

Comment: @unusuario On shoot im sorry, its `$on` not `on`, my apologizes. Give the updated answer a go.

Comment: mmm. I tried this, but nothing happens.. http://plnkr.co/edit/2m97RvcUSQoqcqQOxgc4?p=preview this kills the functionality of my chart

Comment: @unusuario you have declared `var animating=true` at the bottom of your code, it needs to be at the top. Before the `function tick()`, where the rest of your controller scoped variables are. http://plnkr.co/edit/nOlnwz4xX2w8ZFuXJ0pU?p=preview